# Java void function

Tags: java, function, void

I met a function which declared :

```
 void functionName()
```

without any prefix (private, public, protected, static).

It's not very important thing just interesting me how it's work (like a public or private). I know it's easy to test but maybe it have some other benefits.

Comment: The access modifier is `default`, you should google Java access modifiers. Any method can have a `default` access modifier, not just `void` return-type methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
Modifier    Class   Package  Subclass   World
---------------------------------------------
public      Y       Y        Y          Y
protected   Y       Y        Y          N
no modifier Y       Y        N          N     You are here
private     Y       N        N          N
```

When you have no modifier, it'll be available in *class* and *package*, not in *subclasses* and *world*.

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier for that method is called the default access modifier.

It will allow access within same class and package.

See documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 0):

This question might be beneficial to look over. It not only explains the default (or lack of) access modifiers, but reviews all access modifiers.

[In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private?rq=1)